# Configuring Jsx-control-statement codesandbox.io

Tags: reactjs, react-native, codesandbox

I am practicing react on condesanbox.io installed jsx- control-statement dependency. When iam adding any of the control statement it is undefined.

How to configure jsx- control-statements in codesandbox.io.

Answer (score 1):

This question might be couple of month old and its look like the questioner has not find the solution yet,so here is my fix

Solution: Instead of using just jsx syntax inside the return statement wrap the jsx with react fragment,below is the example

```
 return (<>
    {user ? <Component1/>:<Component2/>}
  </>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to use jsx-control-statements in codesandbox.io in the similar way that you might in a local babel environment.

(i guess strikethrough isn't a thing on stackoverflow?) ~~You will have to `import { If } from 'jsx-control-statements'` to get access to the If tag, for example.~~

*edit*:

I've seen people import it in the past (similar to this example https://github.com/PedroBern/react-tiger-transition/issues/2 ) but, as I'm sure you're aware, the jsx-control-statements lib is a babel plugin; the code seen in that example is probably only serving to calm eslint in an older version of control-statements.

If you pull the jsx-control-statements dependency into codesandbox and cast it to a variable via `import whatever from 'jsx-control-statements'`, and look at 'whatever', you'll see that it is a function.  (see the link below for the full code.)

You COULD maybe go down the road of hackifying a dumbed-down version of babel-core, and passing it into `whatever(babel)` but you're better off creating your own If tag that has a `condition` property and conditionally renders children.

https://github.com/AlexGilleran/jsx-control-statements/blob/master/src/index.js

Comment: I added the import statement still no use it is importing but using the tags is undefined